# Which function dependency is not in 1NF?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-normalization

I have done research on normalization. I know if there is no Primary Key or repetition of a column or group of column it is not in 1NF. But I wondered how can we show it be functional dependencies?

For instance, let's say

```
P = (N, C, A, K)
A→ K then (augmentation)  AN → AK Then ANC → AKC

C → K then (augmentation) CN → KC Then CAN → AKC

k(A,N,C) Not
```

Can we say it is not in 1NF or is there a way to change it to not become 1NF or any other example will be appreciated.?

**EDIT**

In other word, my question is, is it possible to determine a function is not in 1NF.
Lets say:

```
R = (A, B, C)
No valid functional dependencies
```

What is the highest normalization form of this?

Comment: I guess FD has to do with the 2NF and not the 1NF, in 1NF we just check whether there are repeating groups of data or not, here is a nice explanation http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Comment: Can you clarify what all this mean? And how it is related to normalization? If you don't fit the normalization form then it is not normalized, period

Comment: @T.S. Please have a look at update

Comment: What system are you (apparently) using, what is the input and what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

"Not in 1NF" does not mean "2NF or higher". A relation in xNF is also in all the lower NFs. "Not in xNF" means it must be in some lower one. Always talk about its highest NF.

If a relation has no (non-trivial) FDs then it is in BCNF. That is because to not be in BCNF it has to have more that one key but a column set smaller than all columns needs a FD to make it a key so the only key is all columns. It might have non-FD JDs though so it might not be in a higher NF.